# Setting a shortcut to "Right Size This Column" in Finder on El Capitan

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

I'm trying to set a keyboard shortcut for "Right Size This Column" in Finder. I've tried setting it under Keyboard > Shortcuts in System Preferences, but this does nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no menu item in Finder named "Right Size This Column" so this shortcut does nothing as no matching menu item can be found.

Comment: There is. It's in the popup menu produced by right-clicking one of the separator bars in column view.